# Why are Angular HTTP requests queued for significantly longer on mobile data compared to WiFi?

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

We have noticed the HTTP requests in our Angular app are being queued for a lot longer when on mobile data.
Could anyone advise as to why?

We are using Angular HttpClient to send a single GET request.

Please see the network resource timing comparison below:

WiFi:
[image: WiFi resource timing screenshot]

Mobile Data:
[image]

As you can see, the same request that was queued for 1.1ms on WiFi is being queued for 2000ms+ on mobile data? We are only sending this one request so I am confused as to why it's being queued at all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

After further testing it appears this is only an issue on iOS devices.

Requests on Android actually appear to be faster on mobile data
(First 3 requests are WiFi, last 3 are mobile data):
[image: Android resource timing screenshot]